# How to find the resistance of a diode operating in reverse breakdown region?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, reverse-breakdown

I am tasked to find the small signal resistance of a diode operating in reverse breakdown region (not forward bias).

> Method 1: Is using the small signal resistance formula correct even in
>   the reverse breakdown region?
>
> $$r_d = \frac{nV_T}{I_D}$$

---

> Method 2: The I-V curve in reverse breakdown region seems to be
>   steeper than the curve in forward bias region. If I use the derivative
>   of current w.r.t voltage, then the resistance is close to zero due to
>   the steep gradient.

Which is correct, or are they both wrong? If so, how do I go about solving this?

Comment: *to find ....reverse breakdown region* OK, it is unclear if this is just a theoretical exercise or that you also will measure a diode and determine the value. Or perhaps both? Your first step is to **think** about what that small signal resistance actually is. Why would Method 1's formula be correct? Does that formula still apply? I think your Method 2, looking at the **slope** of the I-V curve makes more sense. Indeed the current will increase dramatically when breakdown occurs. It might be easier to not force a voltage but use a current measure the V-I curve.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/420681/finding-small-signal-resistance-of-diode-in-reverse-bias although that question also has no answers.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks for the thought. I think you are right. I have checked with my professor and that was what he said.